# bash : input word becomes null with is inputed to a C binary

Tags: c, bash, scripting

I have C binary **program** that receives one-word input. I have a file which contains a list of the words to be inputted to the program, one at a time.

so my script looks something like this"

```
while read line
do
  ./program  ${line}
done < myfile"
```

If I replace .**/program** with **echo**, every argument is printed properly. However, when I input it into the program via alias ($line), program receives blank. Please explain how to fix it and why this is happening.

Comment: Show the part of the C program that handles command line arguments.

Comment: it just processes the argv part of the input to main. when I hardcode the value as opposed to using $line, program behaves properly.

Comment: no interested in your doubts, sir. Nothing personal.

Comment: note what? that's what I used.

Comment: @vehomzzz: your use of "${line}" is missing the double quotes

Comment: @vehomzzz, we have no interest in solving terribly specified problems, particularly with that attitude.

Answer (score 3):

make a debug program to see what is going on...

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    printf("\n");
    // insert code here...
    for(int i = 0; i< argc ; i++)
    {
        printf("argc == %i, argv[%i]==%s\n",argc,i,argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```